# Adding hours and minutes to a date object for time axis

Tags: chart.js

I have a problem working with time formats. As you can see I calculate from the given minutes to hours. Now I need to "add" a time from the previous day to those minutes/hours and having a proper axis labling with days and HH:mm, Example: for the startime var starttime = new Date('2020-03-12T11:00:00') I weant to add the hours to get new dates with the following day since I will add up to 24 h! I don't know how to this. Actuallay you can summarize the issue about adding hours and minute to a date object and hoepfully it gives the next day if you add 24h!

So, from the chart below where you have the hour for eg. 11:20. I want to add to this hour the starttime Date('2020-03-12T11:00:00') to get 22 o'clock (10 pm I think) of the same day or for 23h I get 10 am of the next day: Date('2020-03-13T10:00:00')

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

var HourLabels = [];

MinLables = [54, 83, 155, 192, 206, 238, 285, 307, 335, 367, 431, 444, 495, 548, 604, 651, 680, 721, 777, 789, 859, 936, 980, 1004, 1047, 1089, 1122, 1135, 1200, 1245, 1323, 1381, 1396]

function parseMinToHours(x) {
  MINUTES = x;

  var m = MINUTES % 60;

  var h = (MINUTES - m) / 60;

  var HHMM = h.toString() + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" : "") + m.toString();

  return HHMM;
};

function getHoursLabels() {
  for (var i = 0; i < MinLables.length; i++) // not <=, only < !!!
    HourLabels.push(parseMinToHours(MinLables[i]));
};

getHoursLabels();

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {

    labels: HourLabels,
    datasets: [{
      label: "Messwert",
      xAxisID: 'xAxis0',
      data: [196.0, 222.0, 251.0, 272, 258, 298, 293, 235, 269, 226, 223, 242, 246, 290, 267, 261, 285, 274, 243, 200, 197, 203, 219, 269, 238, 268, 271, 280, 252, 266, 282, 296, 289, 300, 291],
      lineTension: 0,
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'orange',
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      borderDash: [5, 5],
      pointBorderColor: 'orange',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,150,0,0.5)',
      pointRadius: 5,
      pointHoverRadius: 10,
      pointHitRadius: 30,
      pointBorderWidth: 2,
      pointStyle: 'rectRounded'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: "left",
      labels: {
        fontColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        id: 'xAxis0',
        type: "time", // add this!
        time: {
          parser: 'H:m',
          unit: 'hour',
          stepSize: 1,
          min: '00:00',
          max: '23:59',
          displayFormats: {
            hour: 'H', // change to uppercase 'H'.
          }
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Seems pretty well documented here https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html - you can use callbacks too https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly trivial to achieve with [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), which is what Chart.js expects time formats to be.

The code can be greatly simplified as shown in the example below.

Use the Chart.js [time axis display format options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats) to control the formatting of the labels.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var HourLabels = [];
var MinLables = [54, 83, 155, 192, 206, 238, 285, 307, 335, 367, 431, 444, 495, 548, 604, 651, 680, 721, 777, 789, 859, 936, 980, 1004, 1047, 1089, 1122, 1135, 1200, 1245, 1323, 1381, 1396]

for (let i = 0; i < MinLables.length; i++) {
  let starttime = moment('2020-03-12T11:00:00');
  starttime.add(MinLables[i], 'minutes');
  HourLabels.push(starttime)
}

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: HourLabels,
    datasets: [{
      label: "Messwert",
      xAxisID: 'xAxis0',
      data: [196.0, 222.0, 251.0, 272, 258, 298, 293, 235, 269, 226, 223, 242, 246, 290, 267, 261, 285, 274, 243, 200, 197, 203, 219, 269, 238, 268, 271, 280, 252, 266, 282, 296, 289, 300, 291],
      lineTension: 0,
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'orange',
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      borderDash: [5, 5],
      pointBorderColor: 'orange',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,150,0,0.5)',
      pointRadius: 5,
      pointHoverRadius: 10,
      pointHitRadius: 30,
      pointBorderWidth: 2,
      pointStyle: 'rectRounded'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: "left",
      labels: {
        fontColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        id: 'xAxis0',
        type: "time",
        time: {
          unit: 'hour',
          stepSize: 1,
          displayFormats: {
            hour: 'H',
          }
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you I found a smiliar solution. But it is not working because "Moment is noot defined". I use the chart.bundle.min.js but it seems not having moment... although it should 

It there like similiar to other languages where you can just import a package?

Comment: But anyway, thank you! You can show how actually easy chart.js if you know how to use it.;-)

Comment: Chart.js bundles moment to interpret datetimes but doesn't expose it publicly. If you want to use it elsewhere in your code you need to include it separately and use the non-bundled version of Chart.js. See my code snippet (above) where I do exactly that.

Comment: The Chart.js [documentation does mention this](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build): _"The Moment.js version in the bundled build is private to Chart.js so if you want to use Moment.js yourself, it's better to use Chart.js (non bundled) and import Moment.js manually."_

Comment: Ok, but with ypour code above it still say no moment ...So where did you inlcuded moment seperately?

Comment: Underneath the `javascript` code block is a block of `HTML`. You can see there are two `<script src="...">` tags - one for moment and one for Chart.js. Note moment must be included _before_ Chart.js.